# Using a variable in a regex pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
'/^files\/(.+\..+)$/';
```

But I want to replace the "files/" section with a runtime variable.

I tried this:

```
$filePath = "files/";
'/^'.$filePath.'(.+\..+)$/';
```

which didn't work, as well as this:

```
$filePath = preg_quote("files/");
'/^'.$filePath.'(.+\..+)$/';
```

but I still get an error in this loop on the preg_match line, saying that "(" is an unknown modifier.

```
foreach (glob(FILE_PATH."*.*") as $filename) {
    preg_match($pattern, $filename, $matches);
    echo "<option class='file' value='".$matches[1]."'>".$matches[1]."</option>";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

This works...

```
$filePath = 'files\/';
```

...but in actual usage, I'm trying to use a constant declared in another file.

So:

```
define('FILE_PATH', 'files/');
```

...and then trying to use that constant. It can't have the escape character embedded because some other parts of the application need it without the escape character.

Comment: Does `$filePath` contain slashes (`/`)? That conflicts with the regex delimiters you use. You should always regex-escape content you inject into expressions.

Comment: @arkascha he does (that's what `preg_quote` is for). he is just missing a parameter ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hand [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) the delimiter:

```
$filePath = preg_quote("files/", '/');
```

Since you can use [a lot of characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) as delimiters, `preg_quote` cannot know, that you are going to use `/`, so it does not escape it by default. That's what the second (optional) parameter is for.

Otherwise, your second approach (the one using `preg_quote`) is the way to go.

Comment: Perfect! Don't know how I missed that, thank you very much! Will accept the answer as soon as it lets me!